# Jquery to get the value of selected dropdown option

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I'm using following html for dropdownlist,

```
   <select id="dd">
   <option>Select ReportType</option>
   <option value="1">Blocked Details</option>
   <option value="2">Supervisor Input</option>
   </select>
```

i want to get the option value(1/2) in a variable while changing the option.
if i use the following code,

```
   var value = $('#dd :selected').val();
```

i'm getting "Blocked Details/Supervisor" Input in the variable i want to get "1/2"

what is the jquery to get it?

Comment: Your code also seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Tc7Z4/2/ .. which is the browser you are testing against

Answer (score 2):

just use the select element

```
var value = $('#dd').val();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Tc7Z4/)

Comment: if i use this i'm getting "Blocked Details"/"Supervisor Input" in value i want to get "1"/"2" in value

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dd').change(function(){
      alert($(this).val())
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#dd').on('change', function() {
        var id= this.value; 
        alert(id);
});
```

OR

```
var value = $('#dd').val();
var value = $('#dd :selected').val();//this also works
```